# How can I scan a directory of images and place them in my gallery with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is the gallery I have. What I'd like is to have a directory of images scanned and then the images added to the gallery in order by name. So if I put more images later on in the directory they'll be added to the gallery. If anyone could point me in the right direction, like if it's possible, or where I could find info on how to do that'd be awesome. Thanks in advance!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <h3 class="w3-center w3-text-white">Never Ending Light of Day</h3>
  <br>

  <!-- Responsive Grid. Four columns on tablets, laptops and desktops. Will stack on mobile devices/small screens (100% width) -->
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center">
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="6.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="7.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="8.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center w3-section">
    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="2.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src="3.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src=".jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col m3">
      <img src=".jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal for full size images on click-->
<div id="modal01" class="w3-modal w3-black" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
  <span class="w3-closebtn w3-hover-red w3-text-white w3-xxxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
    <img id="img01" style="max-width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP for each loop with glob function like this:

```
<?php 
// Define the directory and filetypes
$dirname = "/images/directory/";
$images = glob("{$dirname}*.png, {$dirname}*.jpg");

foreach($images as $item) {
echo '<img src="'.$item.'" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to PHP. How would I use this? I know to change "/images/directory/" to directory where images are at. But I'm not entirely sure how to implement this with my html.

Comment: the file extension should be .php and the "echo" is 'printing' the items. or, where you put your html div elements.. you can read about the basic syntax at php.net

Comment: I looked at php.net and http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp and I tried using this but with no luck I really think I'm doing this wrong. I put the php above and the html in my post, in a document called home.php  and nothing happened. The image directory was changed to the right folder. php is installed correctly, I'm actually using php to upload images to the image folder. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution. I be used it my website

```
<?php
$dir = "./";
$arr = scandir($dir);
reset($arr);
while (list(, $value) = each($arr)) {
if($value != "." && $value != ".." && $value != "index.php" && $value != ".htaccess"){
echo "<a href = $dir$value><img src = $dir$value height = 240 width = 240>"."</img></a>";
}
}
?>
```